# How to pass value to JPanel class after click button?

Tags: java, swing, oop

How I can to pass value to JPanel class after click button this my Code !

```
  patientFrame

{
    patientFrame.add(new pnlPatientInformation());

    JButton btnShearch = new JButton("Search");

    btnShearch.addActionListe(,,,)
    {
        pnlPatientInformation pnlx = new pnlPatientInformation()
        pnlx.lblID.setText("Value");
    }

    pnlPatientInformation exetend JPanel()
    {
        JLabel lblID = new JLabel();
        pnlPatientInformation.add(lblID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be using a model, which is shared between the two classes.  This would then provide notifications of changes to interested parties.

Start by having a look at:

- [Understanding Model-View-Controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)
- [Observer Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)

for more details.  The intention here is to decouple the code and the management of the diverse elements to make the code more flexible and re-usable in the long term.

This will take some time to implement properly.  In the short term.  The instance of the panel which is displayed on the screen should also be the same instance of the panel you try to update...

```
private pnlPatientInformation patientInformation;
//...
{
    patientInformation = new pnlPatientInformation();
    patientFrame.add();

    JButton btnShearch = new JButton("Search");

    btnShearch.addActionListe(,,,)
    {
        patientInformation.lblID.setText("Value");
    }
```